# Finding the closest values in a sorted list that don't go under/over

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array, binary-search

For my project I have a sorted array of objects of timestamps (in milliseconds) and I need two functions. One function should find the closest time that doesn't go *over* a specific amount, and the other function should find the closest time that doesn't go *under* a specific amount. Also, they should return the indices of values.

For example, if I have this data:

```
let a = [ { t: 50 }, { t: 100 }, { t: 400 }, { t: 800 }, { t: 850 } ];
```

Then `closestUnder(arr, 375)` should return the index for `{ t: 100 }`, which would be `1`

And `closestOver(arr, 450)` would return the index for `{ t: 800 }`, which is `3`

```js
function binarySearchNearest(a, value) {
  if (value < a[0].t) { return 0; }
  if (value > a[a.length - 1].t) { return a.length - 1; }

  let lo = 0;
  let hi = a.length - 1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    let mid = Math.floor((hi + lo) / 2);

    if (value < a[mid].t) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (value > a[mid].t) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
      return mid;
    }
  }

  return a[lo].t - value < value - a[hi].t ? lo : hi;
}

function closestOver(arr, value) {
  let i = binarySearchNearest(arr, value);
  
  let entryIndex = arr[i].t < value && i + 1 < arr.length ? i + 1 : i;

  return arr[entryIndex].t >= value ? entryIndex : -1; 
}

function closestUnder(arr, value) {
  let i = binarySearchNearest(arr, value);

  let entryIndex = arr[i].t > value && i - 1 >= 0 ? i - 1 : i;

  return arr[entryIndex].t <= value ? entryIndex : -1; 
}

let a = [ { t: 50 }, { t: 100 }, { t: 400 }, { t: 800 }, { t: 850 } ];

console.log(closestUnder(a, 375));
console.log(closestOver(a, 450));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simplify the logic

The simplest form of binary search function returns the index where the target value would be inserted to keep the list sorted. This would imply that:

- When an exact match exists in the list, its index is returned
- Otherwise the index of the next higher element is returned
- If there is no next higher element, the length of the list is returned

This last point is the most important caveat to watch out for:
before using the returned index on the list, you must check that it's less than the length.

The implementation of this more classic form is simpler than `binarySearchNearest`.

```
function binarySearch(arr, value) {
  let lo = 0;
  let hi = arr.length - 1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    const mid = Math.floor((hi + lo) / 2);

    if (value < arr[mid].t) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (value > arr[mid].t) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
      return mid;
    }
  }

  return lo;
}
```

Based on this simpler logic, the other functions become simpler too:

```
function closestOver(arr, value) {
  const index = binarySearch(arr, value);
  return index == arr.length ? -1 : index;
}

function closestUnder(arr, value) {
  const index = binarySearch(arr, value);
  return index < arr.length && arr[index].t == value ? index : index - 1;
}
```

In conclusion, it's good to work with the simplest possible building blocks.
`binarySearchNearest` has extra logic to make the result "nearest", which makes it a bit harder to understand, and it also increased the mental burden in its callers.

#### Generalize the sorting order

Currently there are multiple places in the code that refer to the `.t` property of the elements, used as the *search key*. This makes the otherwise generic binary search logic only applicable for the specific use case of items that have a numeric `.t` property. Also, if you ever need to change that property (for example to something more descriptive), then you'll have to change it on many lines.

You could generalize this using a `key` function that maps an item to the value to use to determine sorting order, and passing that function as a parameter to the search algorithm:

```
function binarySearch(arr, target, keyFunction) {
  let lo = 0;
  let hi = arr.length - 1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    const mid = lo + Math.floor((hi - lo) / 2);

    const value = keyFunction(arr[mid]);
    if (target < value) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    } else if (target > value) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    } else {
      return mid;
    }
  }

  return lo;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes complete sense! And it seems to work perfectly as well. Thanks a bunch!